# avoiding duplicate contact roles on opportunity

Tags: trigger

can anyone please help me to write trigger to avoid duplicate contact roles on opportunity.If we try to 
add duplicate contact roles to opportunity,it should give error. I used this trigger but it is not working properly.

```
trigger newwala on OpportunityContactRole (before insert,before update) 

{

List<opportunity> ooo=[select id,Name from opportunity ];

list<OpportunityContactRole> acc=[select contact.Name,contact.id,role from OpportunityContactRole where opportunityId=:ooo];

    for(OpportunityContactRole oppo:Trigger.new)
    {
        for(OpportunityContactRole acd:acc)
        {
           if(oppo.Role==acd.Role && oppo.contact.Name==acd.Role)
            {
                oppo.adderror('This is duplicate contact role');
                system.debug('Oppo.Role'+oppo.role);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to aggregate the data to collect first before you attempt any queries. You'll also need a map to have any type of performance. Here's a typical example I'd write:

```
trigger blockDuplicateRoles on OpportunityContactRole(after insert, after update) {
  // We need these values for our query
  Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>(), conIds = new Set<Id>();
  Set<String> roles = new Set<String>();
  // Keeps track of existing roles
  Map<OpportunityContactRole, OpportunityContactRole> roleMatch =
    new Map<OpportunityContactRole, OpportunityContactRole>();
  for(OpportunityContactRole record: Trigger.new) {
    oppIds.add(record.OpportunityId);
    conIds.add(record.ContactId);
    roles.add(record.Role);
    // This is a composite key using three values
    OpportunityContactRole key = new OpportunityContactRole(
      OpportunityId = record.OpportunityId,
      ContactId = record.ContactId,
      Role = record.Role);
    // Oops, duplicate contact role in this trigger context!
    if(roleMatch.containsKey(key)) {
      record.addError('This role matches an existing contact for this opportunity.');
    } else {
      // Keep track of this role for later...
      roleMatch.put(key, record);
    }
  }
  for(OpportunityContactRole record: [SELECT ContactId, OpportunityId, Role FROM OpportunityContactRole WHERE OpportunityId = :oppIds AND ContactId = :conIds AND Role = :roles]) {
    // Create our composite key for each match found
    OpportunityContactRole key = new OpportunityContactRole(
      OpportunityId = record.OpportunityId,
      ContactId = record.ContactId,
      Role = record.Role);
    OpportunityContactRole incoming = roleMatch.get(key);
    // If this record does not match the Id queried, it is a duplicate!
    if(incoming != null && incoming.Id != record.Id) {
      incoming.addError('This role matches an existing contact for this opportunity.');
    }
  }
}
```

---

## Problems To Avoid

### Unrestricted Queries

```
List<opportunity> ooo=[select id,Name from opportunity ];
```

This will eventually cause your triggers to fail.

### Comparing names

```
if(oppo.Role==acd.Role && oppo.contact.Name==acd.Role)
```

It's naive to presume that you won't have two John Smith's in your database that are actually different people. Always use Id values.

### Unrestricted Nested Loops

```
for(OpportunityContactRole oppo:Trigger.new)
{
    for(OpportunityContactRole acd:acc)
    {
       if(oppo.Role==acd.Role && oppo.contact.Name==acd.Role)
```

This results in multiplicative performance penalties, likely resulting in CPU Limit errors.

The hint to determine this kind of logic error is when you need to have an if statement like the one included here. This means you should be using a Map instead.

Comment: Thank you  sfdcfox